# Quest On Wrapper Class

Tags: java

i have an dought in wrapper class .

when we convert the int - Integer (Boxing Method ) then only i am getting the warning .
Integer [Strikethrough] . kindly suggest me the solution .

[image]

Comment: `Integer a1 = a;`

Comment: Mousehover it and read the popup message that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `Integer` constructor is **deprecated** since Java 9.

Use `Integer.valueOf(a)` instead.

The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) say the following about it:

> It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory valueOf(int) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.

If you use `new`, a new object will be created – always. The static method `valueOf` will use an *integer cache* for small values<sup>1</sup>, so objects can be reused.

---

<sup>1</sup> A Java implementation is free to choose what values may be cached, however, it is [*required*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) by the Java Language Specification to cache the values −128 to 127.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Integer(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) constructor is deprecated, and thus its recommended to avoid using it.

You should use the static method [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) instead:

```java
Integer a1 = Integer.valueOf(a);
```